# How to populate log/println call on every function in Java project?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am about to kick off an android project and currently looking at some sample codes from internet.
However sometimes it is hard to tell which classes are handling which which functions.

So I start to populate:

```
Log.d(LogUtils.DEBUG_TAG + getClass().getName(), new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName() + " starts.");
```

to every function.

I just wonder if there is a quick way to auto populate this statement to every function in project?

Thanks vm,
Joe

Comment: The 'new Exception' part looks scare. Please use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556834/how-do-i-get-the-method-name-from-within-that-method

Comment: Thanks Roy, I tried that before but it didnt work very well for me. those log calls are only for debugging purpose and will be removed before release.

Comment: You could just run your application in the debug perspective in Eclipse, pause it and then use the step buttons to traverse the code. Then you can see exactly what is being called and when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using this code for logs. It automatically give you information about class and method name from which it was called.

```
public static void log(final String msg)
{

    final Throwable t = new Throwable();
    final StackTraceElement[] elements = t.getStackTrace();

    final String callerClassName = elements[1].getFileName();
    final String callerMethodName = elements[1].getMethodName();

   String TAG = "[" + callerClassName + "]";

   Log.d(TAG, "[" + callerMethodName + "] " + msg);

}
```

Here is example:

```
log("Hello World");
```

Gives you:

```
[MainActivity.java] [onCreate] Hello World
```

Now you see that method was called from **MainActivity.java** file with **onCreate** method.

> I just wonder if there is a quick way to auto populate this statement
>   to every function in project?

No you need to add it manually. However you can use boolean variable in my method above to turn logs on/off.

Full source code could be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/dmytrodanylyk/android-library/src/92f1821bc6fc/src/com/dd/utils/log/L.java).